# New to creating a custom adapter

Tags: java, android

Hi i am new to creating a custom adapter, and i am currently in college.
I am finding it hard to figure out why my new Bmi(Bmi bmi) in my base clase Method is never being used. Here is the code please see can you see what i am doing wrong? thanks very much

```
    public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    {
    public   int            height;
    public   int           weight;
    public int bmiTotals = 0;
    public static List<Bmi> bmis    = new ArrayList<Bmi>();


    public boolean newBmi(Bmi bmi) {

    boolean nonValue = (height * weight) < 0;
    if(!nonValue) {

        if (height > 0 && weight > 0) {
            int bm = height / 100;
            int bn = weight;

            bmiTotals = bn / (bm * bm);
            bmis.add(bmi);

            bmiTotals = bmi.bmiTotal;


        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No values entered!",    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
       }
         return nonValue;
    }

  ///////////////////////////////////////This is in a separate class called Bmi 
    public class Bmi {
    public int height;
    public int weight;
    public int bmiTotal;


     public Bmi (int height, int weight, int bmiTotal)
     {
        this.height = height;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.bmiTotal = bmiTotal;
     }
```

}

Comment: It looks like nothing ever calls yours `newBmi()` method. I think you want to do like `bmis.add(newBmi());` somewhere. I guess also, there is never a call to `new Bmi(176, 176, 200);` or whatever. So, you never create the Bmi objects and they are never put into the list.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
public class SMSListAdapter  extends BaseAdapter
{

    private Context mContext;
    Cursor cursor;
    public SMSListAdapter(Context context,Cursor cur) 
    {
            super();
            mContext=context;
            cursor=cur;

    }

    public int getCount() 
    {
        // return the number of records in cursor
        return cursor.getCount();
    }

    // getView method is called for each item of ListView
    public View getView(int position,  View view, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
                    // inflate the layout for each item of listView
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_each_item, null);

                    // move the cursor to required position 
                    cursor.moveToPosition(position);

                    // fetch the sender number and sms body from cursor
                    String senderNumber=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address"));
                    String smsBody=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body"));

                    // get the reference of textViews
                    TextView textViewConatctNumber=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewSMSSender);
                    TextView textViewSMSBody=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewMessageBody);

                    // Set the Sender number and smsBody to respective TextViews 
                    textViewConatctNumber.setText(senderNumber);
                    textViewSMSBody.setText(smsBody);


                    return view;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }
}
```

Complete example: http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/listview-with-custom-adapter.html

Comment: Thank you but i was told to use a custom adapter for the bmi section of my app, i already have implemented a database for another section. My lecturer wants it this way for my project

Comment: Creating adapter is same, you can pass your list and modify as per you requirement.